# Find the common prefix of two strings in idiomatic Swift

Tags: string, swift, text, functional-programming

Other than the brute force approach of iterating over string characters and comparing them, what is the most idiomatic approach to finding the longest common prefix of two Strings in Swift?

For example, the implementation of `commonPrefixWith()` in this snippet:

`let firstString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
let secondString = "The quick brown fox has a pogo stick"
let result = firstString.commonPrefixWith(secondString) // result == "The quick brown fox "`

It has that kind of feel about it of something which has a really elegant functional solution, but I cannot see the best starting point for an approach.

Comment: I think that iterating over string characters and comparing them is the fastest and most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive functional solution that uses simple array operations upon characters. I think this is the one liner you were looking for.

```swift
extension String {
   func sharedPrefix(with other: String) -> String {
      return characters.isEmpty || other.characters.isEmpty ? "" : (characters.first! != other.characters.first! ? "" : "\(characters.first!)" + String(Array(characters.dropFirst())).sharedPrefix(with: String(Array(other.characters.dropFirst()))))
   }
}
```

Edit (by OP) which could be further boiled down to this, in the interests of readability, although admittedly no longer a true one-liner:

```swift
extension String {
    func sharedPrefix(with other: String) -> String {
        return (self.isEmpty || other.isEmpty || self.first! != other.first!) ? "" :
            "\(self.first!)" + String(Array(self.dropFirst())).sharedPrefix(with: String(Array(other.dropFirst())))
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I'd probably boil it down a little further in the interests of readability, although admittedly not really a one-liner any more:

```
extension String {
    func sharedPrefix(with other: String) -> String {
        return (self.isEmpty || other.isEmpty || self.first! != other.first!) ? "" :
            "\(self.first!)" + String(Array(self.dropFirst())).sharedPrefix(with: String(Array(other.dropFirst())))
    }
}
```

Comment: The Array conversion is not needed, just `String(self.dropFirst())` would do. But it still creates lots of intermediate  strings, which is inefficient.

Comment: You should not [delete your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48451847/1187415) and repost it with the same contents, compare https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251732 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297126.

Answer (score 16):

Just wanted to add that there is actually a method in Foundation (since iOS 8/macOS 10.10), which does exactly that:

```
func commonPrefix(with str: String, 
                  options mask: NSString.CompareOptions = []) -> String
```

See https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1408169-commonprefix

While this does not help with finding an idiomatic/functional implementation approach, it might help those who just need to get the job done. :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is another possible "functional" approach. As a tool, we need a method
to "truncate" a sequence according to a predicate. The following uses
ideas from https://github.com/oisdk/SwiftSequence/blob/master/SwiftSequence/TakeDrop.swift.

First define `takeWhile` for a generator type:

```
extension GeneratorType {
    /// Returns a new generator whose `next()` function returns the elements
    /// from the given generator as long they satisfy the predicate,
    /// and then returns `nil`.
    func takeWhile(predicate : (Element) -> Bool) -> AnyGenerator<Element> {
        var gen = self
        return anyGenerator( { gen.next().flatMap( { predicate($0) ? $0 : nil }) })
    }
}
```

Now "lift" the method to sequence types:

```
extension SequenceType {
    /// Returns a new sequence with all initial elements from the given sequence
    /// satisfying the predicate.
    func takeWhile(predicate : (Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> AnySequence<Generator.Element> {
        return AnySequence( { self.generate().takeWhile(predicate) })
    }
}
```

This can be used quite generally, here is a simple example:

```
for i in [1, 4, 2, 5, 3].takeWhile( {$0 < 5} ) {
    print(i)
}
// Output: 1 4 2
```

The "common prefix" function can now be defined as

```
extension String {
    func commonPrefixWith(other: String) -> String {
        return String(zip(self.characters, other.characters).takeWhile({$0 == $1}).map({ $1 }))
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let firstString = "abc1xy"
let secondString = "abc2x"
let common = firstString.commonPrefixWith(secondString)
print(common) // abc
```

Explanation:

`zip(self.characters, other.characters)` enumerates both character sequences
in parallel and creates a (lazy evaluated) sequence of *pairs*:

```
("a", "a"), ("b", "b"), ("c", "c"), ("1", "2"), ("x", "x")
```

`.takeWhile({$0 == $1})` limits this sequence to the initial part of
identical characters in both strings:

```
("a", "a"), ("b", "b"), ("c", "c")
```

`.map({ $1 })` maps each tuple to the second element, returning the array

```
[ "a", "b", "c"]
```

Finally, `String(...)` combines the characters to a string.

---

As of **Swift 4,** sequences have a `prefix(while:)` method taking a 
boolean predicate, which can be used here instead of defining a
custom `takeWhile` method:

```
extension String {
    func commonPrefix(with other: String) -> String {
        return String(zip(self, other).prefix(while: { $0.0 == $0.1 }).map { $0.0 })
    }
}
```

Also strings are (again) a collection of their characters.
*(Tested with Swift 4.0 snapshot from 17.05.2017.)*

Comment: Thanks Martin - awarding this Accepted Answer, due to being both clean and well explained. I learned a lot from your answer beyond just getting the job done.

Comment: Thanks for the swift 4 answer even there is no swift 4 tag available :)

Answer (score 2):

I tried to think as functional as possible :-]

### Correct version

```
extension String {
    func commonPrefixWith(another: String) -> String {
        let a = Array(self.characters)
        let b = Array(another.characters)
        return String(
            a.enumerate()
                .filter { b.count > $0.index && b[0...$0.index] == a[0...$0.index] }
                .map { $0.1 }
        )
    }
}
```

### Wrong version

```
extension String {
    func commonPrefixWith(another: String) -> String {
        let b = Array(another.characters)
        return String(
            Array(self.characters)
            .enumerate()
            .filter { b.count > $0.index && b[$0.index] == $0.element }
            .map { $0.1 }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `"a1b".commonPrefixWith("a2b")` returns "ab" instead of "a" :)

Comment: @MartinR: ok I updated my code. Now it should be correct but not very good by a computational complexity point of view.

Comment: Cool - thanks! I'm equally impressed as mystified about how this works. I think I've got the `filter()` understood, but not the `map()`. Please can you explain a bit? I'm familiar with `$0`, `$1` etc but not the `$0.1` notation and am struggling to look it up.

Comment: Ah - `$0.1` is accessing elements in the tuple. I see now.

Comment: Could you convert it to Swift 4?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an "elegant functional solution" for this problem. Remember that you have a hammer doesn't mean every problem is a nail. However, if you can solve this using Swift's higher order functions if you want to:

```
extension String {
    func commonPrefixWith(aStr: String) -> String {
        var i = 0
        var stop = false

        return self.characters.reduce("") {
            aggregate, char in
            let index = self.startIndex.advancedBy(i)
            if !stop && index <= aStr.endIndex && char == aStr[index] {
                i++
                return aggregate + String(char)
            } else {
                stop = true
                return aggregate
            }
        }
    }
}


let firstString = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
let secondString = "The quick brown fox has a pogo stick"
let result = firstString.commonPrefixWith(secondString) // result == "The quick brown fox "

print("'\(result)'")
```

It's not purely functional because it has side-effects (`i`, `stop`) but it's close.

Comment: Thanks for your input Zoff. I do think the accepted answer is pretty elegant and demonstrates nicely how to do things in a functional way by breaking the problem down into re-usable chunks.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Strings, Arrays and other Collections. Like most String operations, it returns a SubString. You can `String(result)` it, if you want a String.

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {

    func shared_prefix( with other: Self ) -> SubSequence {

        var a = dropLast(0), b = other.dropLast(0)

        while !(a.isEmpty || b.isEmpty) 
              && (a.first == b.first) {

            ( a, b ) = ( a.dropFirst(), b.dropFirst() )

        }

        return dropLast( a.count )

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
let
    a = "It works, which is nice!",
    b = "It works and that's a fact.",
    
    result = a.shared_prefix(with:b)

print( result ) // "It works"
```